# error while loading shared libraries while Zipalign

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zipalign

I am getting this problem all the time when trying to zipalign my apk even after the installation of libc++ and others required according to different post on this.How to solve this problem.Currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory